# Is the helicoid rigid?

Tags: differential-geometry

There is a local isometry between the helicoid and the catenoid. However, they are not globally isometric. Is it true that any *global* isometry of the helicoid onto a regular surface is again a helicoid?

Formally: the helicoid is defined as $H=\{(u \cos(t), u \sin(t), t): u,\ t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. The statement is: "Let $S  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ a regular surface isometric to $H$. Then there exists a rigid motion that maps H onto S".

Comment: Does _regular surface_ include _embedded_ as part of the definition? (Context suggests _yes_, but it seems safest to ask.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the one-parameter isometric family of (minimal) surfaces interpolating between the helicoid and the catenoid? ... There are all sorts of results of Lawson, Meeks, and others (google "rigidity of helicoid") that specify rigidity of constant mean curvature (and, of course, minimal surfaces) that are *not* helicoids. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang my definition of regular surface is: A subset S of R^3 such that each of its points has a neighborhood in S that is diffeomorphic to an open set in R^2.

Comment: So, there is an isometry of the helicoid onto itself, which is not a rigid motion (it is a "screw" motion i.e. a shift in the angle coordinate). However, is there an isometry onto a surface that is *not* a helicoid? (I edited my question) @TedShifrin I am aware of this family, but these isometries are local right?